# Matplotlib import error (expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PosixPath)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-import

I'm facing below error while importing matplotlib(version 3.3.2) on ubuntu server.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 904, in <module>
    rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 803, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 777, in _open_file_or_url
    fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 231, in expanduser
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not PosixPath
```

I have tried upgrading to 3.4.1 but still in `pip list` it is showing as  3.3.2 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Uninstalled matplotlib from all the installed locations and downgraded to 3.0.3

**What I have done**

I had matplotlib installed at two different locations.

1. /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
2. /home/[my username]/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

All the upgrades were getting affected in the package that is installed under path-2. Now I have matplotlib 3.3.2 at path-1 and 3.4.1 in path-2 but python is reading the matplotlib from path-1 as I've seen the same path was given in the output of `pip show matplotlib` terminal command. I have added path-2 to the python path with `sys.path` function but the error remained same as in the question.

At this point I have uninstalled the matplotlib from both the locations, and reinstalled 3.4.2 version at path-2. Now the `pip show matplotlib` got changed to path-2 but it didn't resolve the import error.

I have again uninstalled matplotlib from path-2 and re-installed  matplotlib of 3.0.3 version(downgraded from 3.4.2 to 3.0.3). This resolved the error.

**Remarks**

I have exactly the same configuration in another ubuntu server and matplotlib 3.3.2 version is working without any issue. At this point I'm not sure why it didn't work in this server with 3.3.2 matplotlib but I will surely try to find the root cause.